# Fastest known algorithm for finding simple paths through given set of vertices

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, time-complexity

For an undirected graph $G$ and a given set $S$ of vertices, what is the asymptotically fastest known algorithm for finding a simple path containing
all elements of $S$. What if we require the path to be as short as possible ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See http://thorehusfeldt.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/soda2012_submission_247.pdf.

Comment: Hey, that's a very cool paper! Thanks for the link.

Comment: extra points for the neat decoration on the front page. How did you do that ?

Comment: is it obvious that an algorithm for finding a cycle works for a path?

Comment: @Diego: Add a specified edge between the two vertices which you want to be endpoints of the path.